# Type checking for PyGObject/GTK3

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk, python-typing

I'm new to GTK3 so I thought it would be a good idea to use type checking to have instant access to the docs. However I can't make it work. This is the code I'm using to test if it works.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
mainBox: Gtk.Box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=1)
```

Box is defined inside Gtk.pyi and Pycharm says it is overriden by ToolbarGTK3 but when I run the above code the runtime type is gi.override.Gtk.Box and this is confusing to me. Thanks in advance!